# Summarize BigDecimal grouping by properties using jOOλ

Tags: java, stream, tuples, jool-library

I am trying to summarize Bigdecimal field, using jOOλ library (https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOL)

This is my code, but it works only for summarizing Doubles.
Here I sum field x, and grouping by fields w,z:

```
class A {
    final int w;
    final Double x;
    final int y;
    final int z;

    A(int w, Double x, int y, int z) {
        this.w = w;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
    }
}

Map<
    Tuple2<Integer, Integer>,
    DoubleSummaryStatistics
> map =
Seq.of(
    new A(1, 1.01D, 1, 1),
    new A(1, 2.09D, 3, 1),
    new A(1, 8D, 6, 1),
    new A(2, 119D, 7, 2),
    new A(1, 3.01D, 4, 1),
    new A(1, 4D, 4, 1),
    new A(1, 5D, 5, 1))
.groupBy(
    t -> tuple(t.z, t.w),
    Tuple.collectors(
        Collectors.summarizingDouble(t -> t.x)
    )
);

map.entrySet().forEach(t-> {
    log.info("w={}, z={}, sumX={}", t.getKey().v1, t.getKey().v2,
            t.getValue().getSum());
});
```

Is there a way to use BigDecimal instead Double, using that library?
I need to use only BigDecimal, because I want to use it to summarize financial operations.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your code shouldn't compile. The type of `map` should be `Map<Tuple2<Integer, Integer>, Tuple1<DoubleSummaryStatistics>>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't related to jOOλ directly, but to your usage of the JDK's standard `Collector` that produces doubles as indicated by the method name:

```
Collectors.summarizingDouble(t -> t.x)
```

j ships with its own set of `Collector` construction API in `org.jooq.lambda.Agg`. In your case, you want to use [`Agg.sum(Function)`](https://www.jooq.org/products/jOO%CE%BB/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/lambda/Agg.html#sum-java.util.function.Function-).

Obviously, change your class `A`, first:

```
class A {
    final int w;
    final BigDecimal x;
    final int y;
    final int z;
    ...
}
```

And then:

```
Map<
    Tuple2<Integer, Integer>,
    Optional<BigDecimal>
> map =
Seq.of(
    new A(1, new BigDecimal("1.01"), 1, 1),
    new A(1, new BigDecimal("2.09"), 3, 1),
    new A(1, new BigDecimal("8"), 6, 1),
    new A(2, new BigDecimal("119"), 7, 2),
    new A(1, new BigDecimal("3.01"), 4, 1),
    new A(1, new BigDecimal("4"), 4, 1),
    new A(1, new BigDecimal("5"), 5, 1))
.groupBy(
    t -> tuple(t.z, t.w),
    Agg.sum(t -> t.x)
);

map.entrySet().forEach(t-> {
    System.out.println(String.format("w=%s, z=%s, sumX=%s", t.getKey().v1, t.getKey().v2,
            t.getValue().orElse(BigDecimal.ZERO)));
});
```